# to take a screenshot of a whole listview even if the whole listview elements aren't fully visible in the screen

Tags: android, eclipse, screenshot

I would like to write a code to take a screenshot of the list view even if it is not visible in the screen fully. Can anyone help me in this issue.

Here's is my code and when I try to run this the app crashes, it says that there is null pointer exception in this line //int totalHeight = listView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
        int totalWidth = listView.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
Please help me resolve this issue.

```
Button screenShot;
public String TAG = "";
String[] values = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
        "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" };
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TAG = getClass().getName();

    screenShot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.screenshot_button);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    int totalHeight = listView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    int totalWidth = listView.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);



    screenShot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inside on click",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
            saveBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });
}

public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Inside takeScreenShot method");
    listView.buildDrawingCache(true);
     Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(listView.getDrawingCache());    
    // View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    // rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return listView.getDrawingCache();  

}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is because when `onCreate` is called your view hasn't been drawn yet so you can't get it's height. Try to add this code at the end of your `onCreate` method to wait for the ListView to be drawn and get the height:

```
listView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // You only need this method to be called once
        listView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        // Store the height in a class variable
        mItemHeight = listView.getChildAt(0).getHeight()
    }
});
```

EDIT: I missed `.getViewTreeObserver()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when I tried adding this block it throws a error saying, "The method addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){}) is undefined for the type ListView". Can you please help me solving it...!!!

Comment: Sorry, I missed a method, see my edited answer please :)

Comment: Thanks for your consideration, however when I tried running my code the screenshot is only with the items which are visible on the screen only. But not the entire list view.

Comment: This is because my code snippet is only to get the height of a row, you need to mix my answer with what Usman told you. Please try it by yourself and in a couple of hours when I get to my computer I will try to help you :)

Comment: Hi, I've posted my entire code with all the changes what you and Usman have advised. Please look at the following link and help me fixing this issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996847/trying-to-take-screenshot-of-a-entire-listview