# Trying to take screenshot of a entire listview

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, screenshot

I need to take screenshot of a entire list view irrespective of what is visible in the screen, but at atlast I'm ending up with the Image which consists of details which is visible in the display alone. Please help me resolve this issue.

Here's my code for reference:

```
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TAG = getClass().getName();

    screenShot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.screenshot_button);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    screenRoot = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.screenRoot);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    int width = screenRoot.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = screenRoot.getMeasuredHeight();

    //totalHeight = listView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    //totalWidth = listView.getChildAt(0).getWidth();

    listView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // You only need this method to be called once
            listView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            // Store the height in a class variable
            int width = listView.getMeasuredWidth();
            int height = listView.getMeasuredHeight();

            totalHeight = height;
            totalWidth = width;             

        }
    });

    screenShot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inside on click",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
            //saveBitmap(bitmap);
            Log.i("The Total Height is ",""+totalHeight);
            Log.i("The Total Width is ",""+totalWidth);

            createImage(totalHeight, totalWidth, listView,"screenshot_new");


        }
    }); 

}


public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Inside takeScreenShot method");
    listView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    listView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(listView.getDrawingCache());    
    // View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    // rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return listView.getDrawingCache();  

}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public File createImage(int height, int width, View view, String fileName) {
    Bitmap bitmapCategory = getBitmapFromView(view, height, width);
    return createFile(bitmapCategory, fileName);
}

public File createFile(Bitmap bitmap, String fileName) {

    File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String sdcardPath = externalStorage.getAbsolutePath();
   // File reportImageFile = new File(sdcardPath + fileName + ".jpg");

    File reportImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/screenshot.png");
    try {
        if (reportImageFile.isFile()) {
            reportImageFile.delete();
        }
        if (reportImageFile.createNewFile()) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(reportImageFile);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            bytes.close();
            fo.close();
            return reportImageFile;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to create Image.Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return null;
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int totalHeight, int totalWidth) {


    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalWidth, totalHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    totalWidth  = getTotalWidthofListView(listView);
   // totalHeight = getTotalHeightofListView(listView);

    //totalWidth  = 2160;
    totalHeight = 2160;

    view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(totalWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(totalHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    view.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}


public static int getTotalHeightofListView(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

    int totalHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View mView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

        mView.measure(
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),

                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();
        Log.w("HEIGHT" + i, String.valueOf(totalHeight));

    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (mAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
    return totalHeight;
}

public static int getTotalWidthofListView(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

    int totalWidth = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View mView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

        mView.measure(
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),

                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        totalWidth += mView.getMeasuredHeight();
        Log.w("HEIGHT" + i, String.valueOf(totalWidth));

    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalWidth
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (mAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
    return totalWidth;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android get screenshot of all ListView items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742343/android-get-screenshot-of-all-listview-items)

Comment: @ツPratikButaniツ has already given you the solution :)